# Why I obtain larger bands than expected after minipreparation?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna

guys!
I made a "home made" minipreparation to obtain my plasmid+insert (totalizing approximately 6Kb). But, when I run a agarose gel, I saw a unique band with 10Kb. Why?

Comment: Maybe it was open circular DNA.

Comment: Can you please add a gel image?

Comment: Have you done this same miniprep with a commercial kit? It may not be related to your homemade procedure. It might also be helpful to know how you were doing your ligation and your homemade miniprep protocol.

Comment: If the DNA got damaged in handling it could relax or linearize. That's to say, you have a 6kb vector but it's running about as slowly as the 10kb band in your ladder. You can maximize the supercoiled form by working quickly and gently with the prep.